# WPF: Is it possible to get all elements on which certain attached property set?

Tags: wpf, properties, dependencies

I created a custom attached property which should be set on certain unrelated elements. Purpose of this attached property is to keep Width of all those elements the same. So when any of these elements changes width it should update all other elements with this attached property set. 
I am able to track changes to attached property via "DP property changed event handler" set via UIPropertyMetadata so when any element changes width I will get that notification. What I need to do then is to update all other elements that have this this attached property set.

So I was wondering is it possible to do this? Is there a way to enumerate all DependencyObject instances that have certain attached property set?

I guess this is a bit advanced WPF stuff but it is very specific specific requirement in my WPF application.

Answer (score 3):

You can enumerate visual tree and check if property is set on each of the elements. Something like this:

```
var objectsWithPropertySet = new List<DependencyObject>();
if (RootVisual.ReadLocalValue(FocusIdProperty) != DependencyProperty.UnsetValue)
    objectsWithPropertySet.Add(RootVisual);

objectsWithPropertySet.AddRange(RootVisual.GetAllChildren()
    .Where(o => o.ReadLocalValue(FocusIdProperty) != DependencyProperty.UnsetValue));
```

GetAllChildren() extension method is implemented like this:

```
public static class VisualTreeHelperExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<DependencyObject> GetAllChildren(this DependencyObject parent)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent); i++)
        {
            // retrieve child at specified index
            var directChild = (Visual)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i);

            // return found child
            yield return directChild;

            // return all children of the found child
            foreach (var nestedChild in directChild.GetAllChildren())
                yield return nestedChild;
        }
    }
}
```